# Integrate Magento API V2 to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, magento2

I want to Integrate Magento API V2 which is installed in my localhost and call the V2 API in ASP.NET Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Integrate Magento API V2 using ASP.NET you can use Web Service with SOAP protocol. SOAP is a W3C submitted note (as of May 2000) that uses standards based technologies (XML for data description and HTTP for transport) to encode and transmit application data.

[Web Services with ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx/%22Web%20Services%20with%20ASP.NET%22)

[Magento API SOAP call in C#](http://www.tejaprakash.com/2014/08/magento-api-soap-call-in-c-integration.html)

[Consume Magento Web Services with .NET](http://doghouse.agency/article/consume-magento-web-services-net)